# Can I pass variable in @Value annotation to read a property file, whose key is stored in a String variable?

Tags: java, spring

Can I get the value from a properties file where the value of the key to properties file entity is stored in a variable (contants Class)?

Structure is like: 
properties file

```
x.y.z=123
```

Constant file

```
public static final String abc = "x.y.z";
```

Service class like

```
@Value(${"getConstant("abc").getValueOfProperty()})
public String resource;
```

Comment: If it's a class full of static constants, sure.

Comment: Here I don't only want to read the value from the constants class. The transfer of values is taking place two times here.

Comment: As long as the `String` variable is final, you can use it in `@Value` annotation.

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Comment: Structure is like: properties file---    x.y.z=123     Constant file==     public static string abc = "x.y.z"    Service class like ---   @Value(${"getConstant("abc").getValueOfProperty()})

Comment: As the variable `abc` is not final, you can't use it in @Value.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. the variable abc is final too, but in a different class.

Comment: In that case, you can directly use `@Value("${" + Constants.abc + "}")`

Comment: in that case it is giving me the value of the constant, not the value to which it corresponds to in property file

Comment: The application must be looking for a different properties file. You can use `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:YOUR_PROPERTY_FILE")` over the Service class to specify the property file. Make sure the property file is in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think, we can do like,

```
private final String VALUE_STRING = "${external.value:default}";
@Value(VALUE_STRING)
private String value;
```